# How to return the correct array which include all values inside the second array

Tags: javascript

Let say there are two array.

```
let MotherArray = [
  [30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [7, 8, 9],
];

let arraytoTest = [5,6];
```

What i want is that i want to return the array if
all the value inside the arraytoTest is included in the `MotherArray[i]`

I have tried

```js
let MotherArray = [[30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],[5, 6, 7, 8, 9],[7, 8, 9],];
let arraytoTest = [5, 6];
let result = MotherArray.includes(arraytoTest)
console.log(result);
```

But i don't think this is the correct method.
I also find the array.every() but i think my usage is not correct.

What I want is that I want to return `MotherArray[0],MotherArray[1]` which are `[[30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]` in this particular example
since 5 and 6 are includes inside these 2 arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine [`array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
let MotherArray = [
  [30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [7, 8, 9],
];

let arraytoTest = [5,6];

let found = MotherArray.filter(childArray => arraytoTest.every(num => childArray.includes(num)));

console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) like below.

Or you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with `negative` condition like `filter(x => !arraytoTest.some(y => !x.includes(y)))`. I think with `some` it would be `efficient` because

> The `some()` method executes the `callback` function once for each element present in the array until it finds the one where `callback` returns a *`truthy`* value.

```js
let MotherArray = [
  [30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [7, 8, 9],
];

let arraytoTest = [5,6];
let result = MotherArray.filter(x => arraytoTest.every(y => x.includes(y)));
console.log(result);

let result2 = MotherArray.filter(x => !arraytoTest.some(y => !x.includes(y)));
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want; A combination of `filter` on the mother array and `every` for array you're testing.

```js
let MotherArray = [
  [30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [7, 8, 9],
];

let arraytoTest = [5,6];

let result = MotherArray.filter(arr => arraytoTest.every(x => arr.indexOf(x)>-1));
console.log(result);
```